# jquery ajaxForm uploadProgress cross domain upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, cross-domain

I'm trying to do cross-domain file upload and I need a way to show the upload progress.  using the jquery form plugin I do something like this:

```
$('#fileupload').ajaxForm({
  beforeSend: function() {
    progressBar.style.visibility="visible"; 
  },
  uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
    progressBar.value = percentComplete;
  },
  complete: function(xhr) {
    progressBar.style.visibility="hidden";  
  }
});
```

Only the beforeSend and complete are getting called (checked with alert statements).

In the form I direct the action to the remote server like:

```
<form action="otherDomain.com/blah/blah">
```

Without this custom action the onProgress works.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the property 'uploadProgress' is not supported in all browsers. In some browsers this functionality to get the position, total etc is simply not available.

This is from the official documentation:

uploadProgress
Callback function to be invoked with upload progress information (**if supported by the      browser**). The callback is passed the following arguments: